# Use SUB variable in other sub

Tags: vb.net, ini

I have a Open File button that opens an INI file.

Now I would like to use the path of the file so I can click a Save Button and the file is saved.

This is the code for the Open Button:

```
    Private Sub OpenINIButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenINIButton.Click
    Dim OpenDLG As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenDLG.Filter = "Configuration File (*.ini)|*.ini"
    OpenDLG.Title = "Open INI File"
    OpenDLG.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenDLG.RestoreDirectory = True

    DialogResult = OpenDLG.ShowDialog

    If DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim OpenFile = OpenDLG.FileName.ToString()

        wValue.Text = ReadIni(OpenFile, Isolation, Value, "")

    ElseIf DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then

    End If

End Sub
```

I would like the OpenFile variable in the Save Button, the code I want to use is:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles saveINI.Click

    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(OpenFile, "")
    writeIni(OpenFile, BuildOptions, Isolation, w.Value.Text)
End Sub
```

But the OpenFile variable is not available.

Is there any possibility to set the OpenFile variable Global?
I cannot move it outside the SUB because the Open File button doesn't work anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: This is rather trivially done by simply dropping the OpenFileDialog component from the toolbox onto your form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is very simple. Just declare `OpenFile` outside of sub

```
Private OpenFile as String

Private Sub OpenINIButton_Click( ...
```

Remove `Dim` statement  `Dim OpenFile =` replace with just  `OpenFile =`

Optionally test whether the variable was set at the beginning of `Button2_Click`

```
If OpenFile is Nothing then Exit Sub
```